# Reduction of time complexity of two nested for loop O(N*N)

Tags: c++, performance, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to reduce time complexity of the following nested loop which currently has an O(N*N) time complexity:

```
        for(i = 0; i < N-1; i++){
            for(j = i+1; j < N; j++){
                if((A[j] > B[i])){
                    ctr++; //counting elements satisfying the condition
                }
            }
        }
```

A and B are just two vectors. I expect reducing O(N*N) to O(N). In addition, I doubt that if sorting A and B will help or not! Thanks!

Comment: Pick a language please.

Comment: Thanks @Quimby , it is a piece of C++ code.

Comment: You can't do this in linear time unless the inputs are structured in some useful way.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark , distribution is important. For example, all elements of B can be larger than A, which loops are run completely.

Comment: I think if you know count C_(N-1) you could calculate C_N in O(N) time which might be useful in some cases. Otherwise, I don't think you can do better than O(N^2) without additional special conditions on the array data being true.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for the comment. Could you give some example of this ''structured'' array? Do you mean for example sorted array or something else?

Comment: You can sort the arrays and achieve a time complexity of O(N log(N)). If `A` and `B` are already sorted, you can easily achieve O(N).

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing N*N/2 arbitrary elements, you need N*N/2 operations, i.e. O(n²). Sorting is O(N*log(N)) and can be done separately on both vectors. Sorting 2 vectors is still O(N*log(N)) because constant factors do not play a role in Big-O notation.

If the vectors are already sorted, you could break the loop after the first element which does not satisfy the condition.